# Simple ajax uploader send multiple values to server with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, upload

i'm a web developer from Venezuela, so please excuse my bad english.

I've been searching for a way to upload files using ajax and i found many ajax upload plugins, some were very hard and confusing to integrate to CodeIgniter (which i'm using to develope my web project) until i found Simple Ajax Uploader which i highly recommend: https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader

So, i can finally upload my files with ajax and still use the upload library from codeigniter. The only problem is that i want to send to the server more than the file being uploaded, i want to send the title of that file, but i don't know how to do it with this pluginm i can't see any explicit information about that in the documentation. I only know you can use a "data" parameter in the Uploader instance so you can send more data than the file, but it doesn't seem to work, because the value of the title input in my form is not being saved in my database.

Here's my js code:

```
 function escapeTags(str) {
    return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var btn = document.getElementById('uploadBtn'),
        progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar'),
        progressOuter = document.getElementById('progressOuter');

    var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
        button: btn,
        url: 'index.php/file/upload/do_upload',
        name: 'userfile',
        data: {'file_title': document.getElementById('file_title').value},
        multipart: true,
        method: "POST",
        hoverClass: 'hover',
        focusClass: 'focus',
        responseType: 'JSON',
        debug: true,
        autoSubmit: false,
        startXHR: function () {
            progressOuter.style.display = 'block'; // make progress bar visible
            this.setProgressBar(progressBar);
        },
        onSubmit: function () {
            $("#upload").button("loading");                
        },
        onComplete: function (filename, response) {
            progressOuter.style.display = 'none'; // hide progress bar when upload is completed
            $("#upload").button("reset");

            if (!response) {
                console.log(filename + ' Unable to upload file ' + response);
                return;
            }

            if (response.success === true) {
                alert('<strong>' + escapeTags(filename) + '</strong>' + ' successfully uploaded.');

            } else {
                if (response.msg) {
                    console.log(escapeTags(response.msg));

                } else {
                    console.log('An error occurred and the upload failed.');
                }
            }
        },
        onError: function (response) {
            progressOuter.style.display = 'none';
            alert('Unable to upload file ' + response);
        }
    }); 
    $("#upload").click(function(){
        uploader.submit();
    });      
});
```

Here's my form

```
<div class="modal" id="modalUploadFile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                <div class="well">Sube tu imagen</div>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h5><small>Sube tus memes, pega imágenes a través de URL, los formatos aceptados son GIF/JPG/PNG (Máximo peso: 3MB)</small></h5>
            <form id="upload_file">                    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="well">
                        <input type="file" name="userfile" id="uploadBtn"/>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file_title" class="control-label">Título</label>
                    <textarea name="file_title" id="file_title" rows="4" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="progressOuter" class="progress progress-striped active" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                </div>                                      
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Subiendo..." id="upload">Subir
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my php code

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $status = '';
    $msg = '';
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '3000';
    $config['max_width'] = '2024';
    $config['max_height'] = '2008';
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $status = ['success' => FALSE, 'msg' => $this->upload->display_errors()];
        echo json_encode($status);
    } else {
        $file_info = $this->upload->data();
        $this->_create_thumbnail($file_info['file_name']);
        $data = ['upload_data' => $this->upload->data()];
        $title = $this->input->post('file_title');
        $image = $file_info['file_name'];
        $upload = $this->upload_model->upload($title, $image);
        if ($upload) {
            $status = ['success' => TRUE, 'msg' => 'Imagen subida con exito'];
            echo json_encode($status);
        }
    }
}

public function _create_thumbnail($filename)
{
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'images/' . $filename;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['new_image'] = 'images/thumbs/';
    $config['width'] = 30;
    $config['height'] = 30;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: cant see anything major here which would cause the data not to be saved. Can you confirm that the upload_model is loaded - either auto loaded via your config or loaded in the constructor perhaps?

If the model is loaded and this was not the problem - then its possible that the error is in your model class.

Comment: Yes, i'm loading my model in my controller constructor. What do you mean that the error might be in my model class?

Comment: I just mean that you have not provided the code for your model so I could not verify it as being correct. Another possibility is the URL for your ajax request, are you using a custom url structure of CodeIgniters default? If default, then the line   url: 'index.php/file/upload/do_upload', should be  url: 'index.php/upload/do_upload',    assuming upload is the name of your controller

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. The title data is being sent correctly to the server and it is being inserted in the database. The problem is that it only happens when i asign it a default value. Example: data: {'title': 'default value'}. But when i try to send the value of the input in the form is not being sent, that means that the input value is not being taken. Why could this be happenning? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the uploader when page loads. At this point there is no data in the input field "file_title".

```
data: {'file_title': document.getElementById('file_title').value}
```

Try calling that block of code on click of upload button

```
$('#upload ').on('click', function () { 
  // add your validation here
  ....
   var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
      button: btn,
      url: 'index.php/file/upload/do_upload',
      name: 'userfile',
      data: {'file_title': document.getElementById('file_title').value},
      ......
   });
```

Don't forget to wrap all of it in document.ready, or shortcut.

```
$(function(){
    ....
    // now you can use jquery to get values
    data: {'file_title': $('#file_title').val()},
});
```